# Is there a trope for exotic-sounding names?

Tags: tropes

I'm talking about names that transliterate poorly to the Japanese tongue such as *Light-Raito, L-Eru, Lelouch-Ruruush, Bleach-Bureechu* (yes they all have an l, especially our one-lettered detective). Do manga authors place a premium on unpronounceable names because they sound the most foreign?

Apparently people eyes is a symbol of exotic. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PurpleEyes is there a similar documented trope for L-ven names?

Comment: See: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/835/why-do-some-anime-in-japanese-contain-english and http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/is-there-a-tradition-behind-giving-people-names-from-english-words

Answer (score 1):

Japanese is actually a sound poor language. Unlike English, which can be considered as a sound rich language, Japanese language misses many syllabic sounds like the letter 'l'. There is no specific pronunciation of the letter 'l' from English language in Japanese.

So, the pronunciation for letter 'l' in Japanese is actually eru.

Here is a link to all Japanese sounds possible [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana).